# Create mail fails on Office365 Unified API

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365api, office365-restapi

I have been trying to create an email as illustrated here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/examples-of-office-365-unified-api-calls#msg_eg_manage_me_create_mail_message

However, that seems to fail with a 500 Internal Server Error.
My request is exactly the same to that provided in the example by Microsoft.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We had a regression on the service. The issue has been fix and is being rolled our to the deployments world wide.

Comment: Hi Yina, thank you for your answer. How long would it take for this to get fixed worldwide? I just tried and I still get the same error.